# Git: Merge feature branch into two long-running branches or merge between long-running branches themselves?

Tags: git, git-flow

We have two long-running branches, say `1.x` and `2.x`. 1.x is the currently deployed version for which we only release bugfixes, 2.x is in the works.

When a bug report comes in, we need to apply it to 1.x first but also to 2.x. We use a flow which uses feature branches so a bug fix will typically be developed there. When it's done, we need to get it to both 1.x and 2.x.

There are two main options:

1. Merge the feature branch into both `1.x` and `2.x`
2. Merge the feature branch in `1.x` and then, eventually, merge 1.x into 2.x

Is one generally preferred over the other for some reasons or is it just a matter of personal preference? Thanks.

Comment: I would prefere the first approach because of the following reason. You might merge bugs back to 2.x if you merge 1.x to 2.x

Comment: I should have stated that 1.x is regularly merged into 2.x. We follow a workflow similar to [this](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/11/the-essence-of-branch-based-workflows/).

Comment: Well if it is like that, than I would suggest you stay with your workflow and merge the issue into 1.x and 1.x into 2.x. But thats just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If a bugfix-branch is related to a bug, introduced only in branch 1.x, then it should certainly be applied only to 1.x. Applying it to 2.x may introduce a hidden bug.

If a bugfix-branch is related to a bug of 1.x's and 2.x's common ancestor, then apply it to both. I would recommend to run all possible tests on 2.x after a merge. (Not only checking the fixed feature, but all others.)

Why apply to 2.x immediately? There is a small chance of bug interference, when there's a bug in 2.x that doesn't reveal itself due to a previous bug. The earlier you find it - the better.